# Using Macro to select a file

Tags: c, macros

I have almost 120 files with names like this - a1.txt,a2.txt...
I take an input from the user as an int and using that i must open a particular file.
I tried using macros for that but it isnt working.
here is what i was using.the files are unicode

```
#define concat(d) L"a"#d".txt" 
.
.
.
wchar_t *basefile = concat(d);
```

When i used wprintf to see what concat was generating i found that it only reads till "a" and ignores the rest of the part of the macro.
Please point out what needs to be corrected here or if there are any alternate methods that i could use.Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, you can't use compile-time macros to handle user input taken at runtime.

What you want is the library function `sprintf()`:

http://www.manpages.info/linux/sprintf.3.html

For wide strings, you can use `swprintf()`:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cwchar/swprintf/

Note that a problem with the original `sprintf()` is that it doesn't take an argument for the length of the output buffer, and it could potentially write a string past the end of the buffer and overwrite your stack or your heap.  There are variations on `sprintf()` that fix this, such as `snprintf()`.  But luckily, the wide version `swprintf()` does take an argument specifying output buffer size.

Answer (score 0):

If this number is really user input at run time you'd have to compose the filename then with something like `snprintf` or so. Your method would only work if this is a number (in fact whatever token) that is known at compile time to identify your file.

So something like

```
#define D 42

.
.
.
wchar_t *basefile = concat(D);
```

should work.